# react-native-router-flux pop fails to return to the previous scene

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

Navigating to `List` screen, and from there to `Item`, I would expect back button to return me to `List`, but instead it returns me to the initial scene `Home`.

I have a very simple navigation setup:

```
<Stack key="root">
  <Drawer
    key="drawer"
    contentComponent={DrawerContent}
    drawerWidth={300}
   >
     <Scene key="home" component={HomeScreen}/>
     <Scene key="list" component={ListScreen}/>
     <Scene key="item" component={ItemScreen} back />
   </Drawer>
  </Stack>
```

And a list of simple buttons in the `DrawerContent` component like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={Actions.home}>
  <Text>Home</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

The `ListScreen` includes buttons that call this:

```
Actions.push('item')
```

Comment: back to prvious scene with Actions.pop() not push.

Comment: yeah, I was using push to goto the scene not to leave it. I am using the built in title bar back button to go back. I also tried with pop, but with the same effect.